# TSQL return predefined row when no rows found

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, entity-framework-core

Working with Microsoft SQL Server: There are multiple systems, each one has set of errors (four digit numbers) that map to an Error Group (string).  There is one exception:  if the error string is NOT in the list below, it should fall into a predefined Error Group.

Example:

```
System 1:
Error Group 1: 2001, 2003, 6538, 6540, 6542, 6544, 6546
Error Group 2: 2002, 6539, 6541, 6543, 6545, 6547, 6549
Error Group 3: 1000, 1001, 1002, 4001, 4007, 5001, 5002 AND ANYTHING ELSE!

System 2:
Error Group 1: 6016, 6533, 6540, 6542, 6544, 6546
Error Group 2: 6541, 6543, 6545, 6547, 6549 AND ANYTHING ELSE!
Error Group 3: 1002, 4001, 4007, 5001, 5002
```

The table:

```
SystemId (int): 1, 2, etc
ErrorGroup (string): "Error Type 1", ...
Error (int?): the four digit number
```

Finding the errorGroup is straight forward:

```
SELECT ErrorGroup 
FROM table 
WHERE SystemId = 1 AND Error = 2002
```

The goal is one query that will return the error group when the error is found and the "default" error group when the error is not found.  There is flexibility in changing or modifying the data to make this happen.

What would it look like in Linq?

Comment: You've tagged EF and also `t-sql` - if you want a linq query, what relevance is `t-sql`?

Comment: Stu, simple:  I want to know how to preform the query in both worlds as to be more educated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the T-SQL ISNULL system function to return a predefined constant value if the result of the query is empty.

```
SELECT ISNULL(
    (SELECT ErrorGroup FROM table 
    WHERE SystemId = 1 AND Error = 2002), 
    'Default Group')
```

Instead of the string literal, another query can also be used.

As for Linq, `DefaultIfEmpty` can be used to set the default value of the query if there is no result.

Comment: Did you test this -- I would expect you would put the ISNULL in the select statement (eg `SELECT ISNULL (ErrorGroup, 'Default Group') AS ErrorGroup FROM...`

Comment: Here is the documentation -- none of these show passing a select statement to ISNULL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Hogan Yes, I tested it and it worked. In this case, SQL Server treats an empty result as a null value.

Comment: Although the query will work it does require and additional step to determine what the 'Default Group' is for each system. Ideally you would either create an entry to signify the default or create a table to hold the defaults for each system.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you will always just return one row the best way to do this is to use coalesce -- this will work on all versions and platforms of SQL.

```
SELECT COALESCE(ErrorGroup,'Default Group') AS ErrorGroup
FROM tablename
WHERE SystemId = 1 and Error = 2002
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as a SQL solution goes here is a possibility.

I created the table as:

```
CREATE TABLE ErrorData (SystemID int NOT NULL,
                        ErrorGroupID int NOT NULL,
                        ErrorCode int NULL)
```

I added data based on you info above:

```
INSERT INTO ErrorData (SystemID, ErrorGroupID, ErrorCode)
values (1,1,3001),(1,1,3003),(1,1,6538),(1,1,6540),(1,1,6542),(1,1,6544),(1,1,6546),
       (1,2,2002),(1,2,6539),(1,2,6541),(1,2,6543),(1,2,6545),(1,2,6547),(1,2,6549), 
       (1,3,1000),(1,3,1001),(1,3,1002),(1,3,4007),(1,3,6542),(1,3,5001),(1,3,5002),
       (1,3,null),
       (2,1,6016),(2,1,6533),(2,1,6540),(2,1,6542),(2,1,6544),(2,1,6546),
       (2,2,6541),(2,2,6543),(2,2,6545),(2,2,6547),(2,2,6549), 
       (2,3,1002),(2,3,4001),(2,3,4007),(2,3,5001),(2,3,5002),
       (2,2,null)
```

You will notice I inserted a value with NULL for the error code to identify the default Error Group

I can then query the data and get the proper ErrorGroup, or the default one using this query

```
SELECT TOP 1 ErrorGroupID FROM ErrorData WHERE SystemID = 1 AND (ErrorCode = 3003 OR ErrorCode IS NULL) ORDER BY ISNULL(ErrorCode,99999)
```

If i query for an Error Code that doesn't exist i will get the default Error Group

```
SELECT TOP 1 ErrorGroupID FROM ErrorData WHERE SystemID = 1 AND (ErrorCode = 9999 OR ErrorCode ISNULL) ORDER BY ISNULL(ErrorCode,99999)
```

Comment: This method will allow you to define in data what the default is and have a different default for each system without having to know what it is.